# How to change the selector in the query using Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to test my table, in order to do that I first check if the table contains a specific test data and then I want to select the delete button and click on it. My problem is **how can I select the delete button when I selected the row?**

Here is my Cypress script:

```
describe('Form', () => {  
  it('table contains test datat', () => {
    cy.get('table').contains('td', 'Awww, c\'est un bummer');
  }) 
})
```

and my table code :
[image]

From what I understand my script put a selector on the cell, so I should be able to chain it with `.then()` but I don't know how to get the delete button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make it using:

```
  it('it deletes the selected line', () => {
     cy.contains('td', 'Awww, c\'est un bummer')  // gives you the cell 
      .siblings()                            // gives you all the other cells in the row
      .contains('button', 'Annuler')               // finds the delete button
      .click()
  })
```